# How to configure ports and routes for ASP.NET Core app on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

How can I set a concrete working port for my ASP.NET Core application which I deployed on Azure portal as an App Service. By default Azure virtual machine sets random ports for my app like that:

[INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:4340"
[INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:8105"

Answer (score 1):

You can only use port 80 and 443 on an Azure Web App, see [the docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening)

> The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports; applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from the internet.
> However, applications may create a socket which can listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit they be on the same machine, will fail. See the next topic for additional detail.

Once you deploy a .Net Core Web App to Azure App Services it will start listening on those ports by default unless specified otherwise. So stick to the default ports and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, but why my apps into app service uses ports like 4340, 8105? It's text from their logs:
2020-09-26T07:58:41.0730505+00:00  [INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:13605" (d826f4b8)
2020-09-26T07:58:41.0834948+00:00  [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. (dcaefe54)

Comment: @ivan_spb_dev you have deployed the app to an azure web app, not a VM do you? Can you post your program.cs file content?